# Xpages - popupmenu control inside a Details facet on DataView control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to place a drop down of actions under a panel inside Details facet on a dataview control. Eventhough it shows up, it does not show the drop down on clicking. Could anyone help solving it?

Here is my code:

```
<xp:table>
<xp:tr>
    <xp:td><xe:popupMenu id="popacts">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:basicLeafNode label="Assign To Tester"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            <xe:basicLeafNode label="Assign to Developer"></xe:basicLeafNode>
        </xe:this.treeNodes>                                
        </xe:popupMenu><xp:link escape="true" id="link1" loaded="true" text="Actions">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
         <xp:this.script>
          <![CDATA[XSP.OpenMenu(thisEvent,#javascript:getComponent('popacts').getMenuCtor()})]]>
         </xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:link>
   </xp:td>
</xp:tr></xp:table>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It should be openMenu , not OpenMenu

This will work

```
XSP.openMenu(thisEvent,#{javascript:getComponent('popacts').getMenuCtor()})
```